# Is it ever a good idea to use results of multiple algorithms as features?

Tags: machine-learning

Let's say that I have a vector of features that I use to get a single result back using some machine learning algorithm.

I thought about using multiple variations of that algorithm to get multiple results back and then simply concatenating them together into one big features vector for a new algorithm to give me that one result back.

Would that enhance accuracy or make it worse?

Answer (score 4):

This is widely used method, called **stacking**, see e.g.
[Bagging, boosting and stacking in machine learning](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/18891/bagging-boosting-and-stacking-in-machine-learning)

To answer your question: yes, it is very useful in some cases. 
If you cook it properly with folding, it almost sure to have quality no worse than a single model.