# How do I optimize decision tree regression algorithm implemented in R?

Tags: r, regression, machine-learning, cart

I'm only getting an accuracy of 59% using the following implementation calculated using the `diag(sum(cm))` and `sum(cm)` functions. How can I increase this accuracy?
The dataset is of heart patients from UCI with 303 rows and 14 parameters.

The script I've implemented is:

```
    dataset = read.csv('data.csv')

# Encoding categorical data  
    dataset$Sex = factor(dataset$Sex,
                         levels = c('1', '0'),
                         labels = c(1, 0))  
    dataset$num = factor(dataset$num,
                           levels = c('0', '1','2','3','4'),
                           labels = c(0, 1, 2, 3, 4))  
    dataset$chesp.pain.type = factor(dataset$chesp.pain.type,
                           levels = c('1','2','3','4'),
                           labels = c(1, 2, 3, 4))  
    dataset$fasting.blood.sugar = factor(dataset$fasting.blood.sugar,
                           levels = c('0', '1'),
                           labels = c(0, 1))  
    dataset$exercise.induced.angina = factor(dataset$exercise.induced.angina,
                           levels = c('0', '1'),
                         labels = c(0, 1))  
    dataset$electrocardiographic = factor(dataset$electrocardiographic,
                                         levels = c('0', '1','2'),
                                         labels = c(0, 1,2))  
    dataset$slope.of.peak.exercise = factor(dataset$slope.of.peak.exercise,
                                      levels = c('1','2','3'),
                                      labels = c(1,2,3))  
    dataset$thal = factor(dataset$electrocardiographic,
                                      levels = c('0','1','2'),
                                      labels = c(0,1,2))  


#Splitting the dataset into training and test set
#install.packages('caTools')
    library(caTools)  
    set.seed(123)   
    split = sample.split(dataset$num, SplitRatio = 0.8)  
    training_set = subset(dataset, split == TRUE)  
    test_set = subset(dataset, split == FALSE)  


#Feature scaling
    training_set[,c(1,4,5,8,10,12)] = scale(training_set[,c(1,4,5,8,10,12)])  
    test_set[,c(1,4,5,8,10,12)] = scale(test_set[,c(1,4,5,8,10,12)])  


# Fitting Decision Tree Classification to the Training set
# install.packages('rpart')
    library(rpart)  
    classifier = rpart(formula = num ~ .,
                   data = training_set)  

# Predicting the Test set results
    y_pred = predict(classifier, newdata = test_set[-14], type = 'class')  

# Making the Confusio1n Matrix
    cm = table(test_set[, 14], y_pred)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could experiment with (back-)pruning the tree.

Read  `?rpart.control`, and vary the `minsplit`, `cp` and `maxdepth` arguments.

The call to rpart would have 1 additional argument and look like this

`rpart(formula = num ~ ., control= rpart.control( ???your turn??),
                   data = training_set)`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I did what you said but it still has no effect on the accuracy. Can you guide me as to what should be values of cp, maxdepth and minsplit?

Answer (score 0):

Changing `cp` very small say `1e-10`, and `minbucket` very small, say `1,` will make the model more complicated and fit the training data better.

Couple of things you may need to pay attention.

1. You may never get the improvement too much by changing the parameters. Think about the term of "irreducible error". If the data is hard to model, may be 59% accuracy is good enough for any model and cannot be improved too much.
2. If you are targeting on improving the accuracy, you may overfit data, i.e., it will work well on the training data, but cannot be generalized.
3. In general, tree model is a "high bias" model (like a linear model). And we may not get a very high accuracy from tree. A common approach is using bagging or boosting on tree. See following question for details.  [Bagging, boosting and stacking in machine learning](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/18891/bagging-boosting-and-stacking-in-machine-learning/19053#19053)