# How do we call the concept "gradually increasing the difficulty of training"?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks

Do we have the concept of "gradually increasing the difficulty of training" in machine learning?

What is the term used to describe this strategy?

Thanks.

Comment: what does "difficult of training" means? Not clear but this sounded like  boosting https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/18891/bagging-boosting-and-stacking-in-machine-learning .

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Curriculum learning** (possibly coined [here](https://ronan.collobert.com/pub/matos/2009_curriculum_icml.pdf)) is a commonly used term for gradually increasing the difficulty in some learning problem. It's often used in reinforcement learning applications.